# Converting a for loop to a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, computational-complexity

I'm trying to convert the following for loops to sums, but I'm getting a little confused about the upper limits:

1. `for(i=2; i <= n; i*=i)`
2. `for(i=n; i > 1; i=sqrt(i))`

We can suppose that each iteration does $\Theta(1)$.

So for 1 we have $\Large\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^m 2^{2^i} $, and we want to know for what m we have $2^{2^m} <n$ so we get that $m=\log\log n$, is that right?

For 2, $\Large\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^m n^{\frac 1 {2^i}} $, trying to use the same method, maybe since we want to find the smallest $i$ such that $\large n^{\frac 1 {2^i}}\ge2$ so we get that: $\log\log n \ge i$ so $m=\log\log n$ again?

Comment: change of variable in the loops : $\text{for(i=2; i <= n; i*=i)}$ with $u = \ln i$ becomes  : $\text{for(u= ln 2; u <= ln n; u *= 2)}$ and with $v = \ln u = \ln \ln i $: $\text{for(v= ln ln 2; v <= ln ln n; v += ln 2)}$

Comment: Why is it $u *= 2$? @user1952009

Comment: $i \leftarrow i^2$ with $u = \ln i$ becomes $u \leftarrow 2 u$

Comment: Also, it becomes $\displaystyle\sum_{i=\ln\ln 2}^{\ln\ln n}i \ln 2$? @user1952009

Comment: you didn't say what to do in the for loop. $ for(i=2; i <= n; i*=i)f(i)$ becomes $\sum_{w = (\ln \ln 2) / \ln 2}^{(\ln \ln n) / \ln 2} f(\exp(\exp(w \ln 2 )))$ by the change of variable $w = (\ln \ln i) / \ln 2 $

Comment: note that in the general, you can't always transform a for  loop into a $\sum_{x = a}^b f(x)$ but you can always define a sequence $u_1= \ldots$, $u_{i+1} = g(u_i)$ for which $u_n$ gives the result of your for loop, and this way you can extend the trick to formalize mathematically any computer program  (by the equivalence between recursively enumerable sets and turing  machines.. or something like that)